# Cannot upload public key to create a secure connection in bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

According to the README file, it says

> Using the 
>      BlueMix popup that enabled you to download the client, you will find
>      the message, "Now, upload the public key that you generated using 
>      your local machine" and Browse button; click the button to upload
>      you RSA key to enable your connector.

I used Chrome and FF and still didn't see the upload button. I wanted to upload a the screenshot of the popup but I don't have any reputation to do so. Sorry. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What README are you referring to?

Comment: Dido to Jake Peyser's question. Not enough context to make offer a solution

Comment: I got an answer from IBM support, apparently it's conflicting description from the README and the upload popup screen. There is no upload button, it just marks a checkbox as it uploads automatically the file once it's selected.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are referring to Cloud Integration. Yes, you just needed to upload the cert using the browse button, then the cert is uploaded automatically and a check appears to show that it was successful.